# Don Box - Essential COM: Why define the creation operator as a non-member function when the deletion operator is a member function?

Tags: c++, com

## Essential COM, Don Box

### Chapter 1, *Abstract Bases as Binary Interfaces*, Page 18

If you do not have a copy of this book, and are curious about Component Object Model (COM) scroll down to the bottom where I give some further background information.

The `IFastString` interface class is defined as

```
// ifaststring.h
class IFastString
{
    public:
    virtual void Delete() = 0;
    virtual int Length() const = 0;
    virtual int Find(const char*) const = 0;

};

extern "C"
IFastString* CreateIFastString(const char* psz);
```

The `FastString` class is defined as

```
// faststring.h
#include "ifaststring.h"

class FastString : public IFastString
{
    private:
    const int m_ch;
    char *m_psz;

    public:
    FastString(const char *psz);
    ~FastString();
    void Delete();
    int Length() const;
    int Find(const char *psz) const;
};
```

Finally, here is the implementation of `FastString`

```
// faststring.cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <faststring.h>

IFastString* CreateFastString(const char *psz)
{
    return new FastString(psz);
}

FastString::FastString(const char *psz)
    : m_ch(strlen(psz))
    , m_psz(new char[m_ch + 1])
{
    strcpy(m_psz, psz);
}

FastString::~FastString()
{
    delete [] m_psz;
}

void FastString::Delete()
{
    delete this;
}

int FastString::Length() const
{
    return m_ch;
}

int FastString::Find(const char *psz) const
{
    // find algorithm implementation goes here
}
```

When I first saw this code it appeared slightly "odd" to me. I am confused as to why the creation function is not defined in a similar way to the delete function.

It would seem to me there are two possible modifications to this code. As far as I can see, both of the following choices would work.

<s>1: The creation function could be made a member function. (?)</s>

I initially thought this would be possible however I now believe this cannot be done because C++ class member functions cannot be defined with `extern "C"` linkage.

Therefore the choice to define the creation function as a non-member is not completely arbitrary.

2: The deletion function could be made a non-member function. It would then more closely match with the creation function.

```
// h (interface)
extern "C" // is this needed?
void DeleteIFastString(IFastString *s);

// cpp
void DeleteIFastString(IFastString *s)
{
    delete s;
}

// remove the virtual void Delete() function from both
// IFastString and FastString classes
```

The only reason I can think for this decision not being taken is that it polutes the global namespace with another non-member function. However on the other hand, having a syntactically similar "deleter" to your "creator" function is arguably desirable.

Is there any other reason why the deleter has been implemented as a member function?

### Further Background Info (COM)

The purpose of the ideom in the above example is to solve two problems:

1. A dynamic library should be designed with a defined interface which does not change.

This is so that the implementation can be changed without requiring modification to client code. Someone can update the "FastString" dynamic library keeping the interfaces constant so that client code can link to a new version of the dynamic library without requiring changes to the client source.

2. A dynamic libary should be designed with an exposed object size which does not change.

This is so that a changed dynamic library can be shipped to a client and the compiled client code can load the dynamic library code, and functions will access data at the correct offset.

Consider the following: If member variables of an interface class are changed, then the offsets or locations of where those data are stored in memory will change. If an interface class is exposed to client code, then different compiled versions of that interface class will be binary incompatiable.

3. If the client code is compiled with a different compiler to the compiler used to compile the dynamic libary code, then the dynamic libary should be loadable at runtime by the client and work as expected.

The reason this may not happen is if the compilers used compile code in an incompatiable way. For example, virtual functions have multiple possible implementations, as the C++ standard does not define how polymorphism and virtual functions should be implemented. Different compilers may produce different binary codes which are incompatiable.

Don Box describes this in more precision than I have here over the course of several pages. Hopefully I presented enough information for this to be understandable.

COM solves the above three issues by defining an interface class with no member variables, along with an implementation class the data members and functions of which are completely inaccessible to client code. In addition to this, all functions which touch member data of the implementation class are compiled with the same compiler. (The compiler used to compile the dynamic library.) This means that the functions and data are compiled by the same compiler and are thus binary compatiable. Finally, user accessible functions are defined with external C linkage so that they are compatiable and can be linked with client code compiled with a different compiler.

It is worth noting that the above assumes the archetecture is the same. For example, COM does not solve the problem of x86 code being incompatiable with ARM systems. (Probably obvious but worth mentioning to avoid confusion.)

Comment: Delete is called on the interface ie you have to already have an object to call delete on.  For creation there is no interface (or existing object); if there was you would already have an object and have no need to call create.

Comment: An `extern "C"` factory function without a corresponding deleter of the same language linkage seems very weird to me. Cleanup is already only possible from C++... If the language linkage is indeed moot and doesn't serve another purpose it becomes just a philosophical question. With an `extern "C++"` factory, it can just as well be a static member function.

Comment: This is a didactic example to teach you the COM design principles.  There is always a separate factory function, CoCreateInstance() is the canonical one.  Releasing the object is always done with an interface member function, IUnknown::Release().  Avoid thinking C++, the client programmer might be using any language and C++ has no direct support for interfaces, albeit that a C++ class can be wrangled into a reasonable approximation.

Comment: COM is accessible to C (and other C-compatible languages - VB, C#, etc), so you can't think of COM in C++ terms.

Comment: I will add to other "COM is not C++" comments that in fact, yes, COM does solves the problem of "the problem of x86 code being incompatible with ARM systems". COM defines how you can communicate between two processes and two machines through RPC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/inter-object-communication this has been used for many years to allow x86 <-> x64 COM communication on Windows

Comment: @SimonMourier You appear to be talking about something completely different. A shared library compiled for an ARM archetecture will not be loadable to an executable running on x86. COM does nothing to solve this "problem". I don't personally consider this an issue because when would one x86 processor interface with memory (RAM) on another ARM system. It doesn't make sense as a question.

Comment: No, I'm talking about COM, you seem to imply COM is only about a shared library that can be loaded into a given process, but a COM "server" can be out-of-process. COM defines also how to implement IFastString in an ARM64 process and use it in an x86 process. That's another reason why you must not think of COM in C++ terms.

Answer (score 1):

COM doesn't expose C++ class constructors or static class member functions for instance creation.  The COM function is `CoCreateInstance`, but that's not the only possibility.

Some COM interfaces are constructed via a method on `IClassFactory`, but you'll still need a mechanism to acquire an `IClassFactory` (`CoGetClassObject`)

COM doesn't use a `Delete` method, the relevant member function is `Release`.  All COM interfaces inherit from `IUnknown`.

It's the responsibility of the object exposing the interface to know how to dispose of itself if all references to it are released.

You could be running code that accesses different implementations of the *same interface* on different objects that have different sizes,
and are implemented in different DLLs.  Which static function would you call to delete it?  It's not your problem.
That's the point of going through interfaces - you don't care what the implementation is.

It's possible to construct COM interfaces in languages other than C++, and the caller wouldn't know.

The point #2 above is irrelevant; the size of the object doesn't matter to the caller.  COM exposes interfaces, not objects.  What matters is the binary layout of the interface, which is (in practice) defined as "What the MS compiler does with this C++ definition".

Comment: To clarify point #2: This is why the interface has to have no member data. If it did have member data and the member data could change depending on implementation revision then it wouldn't work, becuase the memory alignment of the interface would change. That is what I meant by point #2. (Also by definition it would no longer be an "interface" but this is a circular argument.)

Comment: Consumers of an interface never access member data directly & even if an interface contained member data, adding or deleting member data doesn't affect the layout of the vtable.

Comment: From the book example: don't confuse FastString with IFastString.  IFastString is the exposed interface, FastString is a class that implements IFastString.

Comment: IUnknown is in Chapter 2.